# Excel icon not showing open workbooks in dock

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, dock

I have a coworker who no longer sees the options to click on open workbooks. Here's how it looks when it's working correctly:
[image]

Note the Workbook1 & 2 showing up. He does not have that on his Mac. Both running 10.9.1 with latest update of Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag the icon off the dock and add it back in from `~/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011` and it'll come right back.

It seems the dock shortcut is malfunctioning - it's been happening since he upgraded versions.